# Can you grant access to controllers/views for non-authenticated users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 3 application which uses asp.net authentication. I have just created a custom errors controller and a couple of views for unknown errors and 404’s. This works fine when I am logged into the application but if an internal server error happens during logon I would like to display the error/unknown view. However I just keep getting redirected back to the login as I am not authenticated.

I have added a location path for ‘Views/Error’ to my Web.config to allow access to all users but I am guessing it’s the controller access that is causing the redirection.

Is there any way you can allow this in MVC or do I need to think of another solution? Just did not want to add a generic message to the login page as that’s what my unknown error view is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it better to use the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controllers. You can use that on your controllers or views that require authorized user. This way everyone will have access to your Error controller.

Comment: I do use this on my controls but what I need is non authenticated(authorized) users to access my errors controller. At the moment asp.net authentication is kicking in and not allowing me to run any action methods on this controller as there is no user logged in.

Comment: Have you specified anything in you web config like: <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization> as this will no longer be needed if your using the [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: Oh I get you, just get rid of that and Authorize on all my controllers. Not both together.

Comment: That's it. I only use the [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: The issue that I seem to have is one of Authentication and Authorisation. Forms Authentication will not let me past the login screen as I am not authenticated. If I remove this then I am removing Forms Authentication from my application.

Comment: Are you using a custom membership provider or the built in .net one? If you are using your own is the HttpContext.Current.User getting populated?

Comment: You should still set up authentication in the web.config (i.e. use forms authentication, set the logon url, etc), but the authorization piece should NOT be done in the web.config, you should handle that via the `[Authorize]` attribute. If you want a non-authenticated user to access an action, simply do not decorate it with the `[Authorize]` attribute.  If you decorate your controller with the `[Authroize]` attribute, then all action methods in the controller require a user to be authenticated.

Comment: Thanks guys finally got it working. Removed the <authorization> section from my Web.config and ensured all the controllers were set with [Authorize(Roles = "MyRoles")] and everything works as expected. Have up-voted all answers as they are good and valid.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a location section to your web.config file?

the url should be the url of your error pages. Within the location element specify authorization as allow users="*"

or, add the authorise attribute to your error controller or actions with users set to "*".

You are sort of correct though. You need to change who is authorised to access your error controller. the authorise attribute and the location element both allow you to do this.

Simon